# Filter json results from a file

Tags: json, bash

I'm trying to write a script that reads all lines of .txt file. Each line is valid JSON with fields: `saddr`, and `data`. I want to get Bytes size (with `wc -c`), but can't do that.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
echo $line |
jq -r '.data' |
bytes=$(wc -c)
if (( $bytes > 200 )); then
    echo $bytes
fi                                                                       
done< "testear.txt"
```

Example `testear.txt`:

```
{ "saddr": "157.130.222.66", "data": "9f00032a30000000" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set `bytes` in a pipeline, with the command:

```
echo $line | jq -r '.data' | bytes=$(wc -c)
```

However, the commands in a pipeline are run in a subshell, so environment variables set there will not be available in the top-level shell.

Instead, try this:

```
bytes=$(echo "$line" | jq -r '.data' | wc -c)
```

- so that you're setting `bytes` at the top level shell.